# Is it okay to put singularities into the wave function to test behavior around unstable potentials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, potential, stability

$$
\psi(r)=\sqrt[4]{\frac{ a}{8\pi^3 }}\frac{ \exp (-a r)}{r^{1.25}}
$$

The wave function above is an example of a function that is normalizable in 3D space and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

$$
-\psi ''(r)-\frac{2 \psi '(r)}{r}
+
\left(
\frac{a }{2 r}+\frac{5 }{16 r^2}
\right)
\psi (r)
=
-a^2 \psi (r)
$$

It appears to be a solution of Schrodinger's equation with a potential of the form $V(r)=V_1/r+V_2/r^2$ which is classically unstable. The potential's radial force is always outward.

Another example of a normalizable wave function with a singularity is 
$$
\psi(r)
=
\sqrt[4]{\frac{2 a^3}{\pi ^3}}
\frac{
\exp (-a r)}{r^{0.75}}
$$
satisfying
$$
-\psi ''(r)-\frac{2 \psi '(r)}{r}
+
\left(
-\frac{a}{2 r}-\frac{3}{16 r^2}
\right)\psi(r)
=
-a^2 \psi(r)
$$
In general 3D space, the condition of normalizability of a wavefunction with one singularity
$$
\int_0^\epsilon (r^2dr) \left(\dfrac{f(r)}{r^b}\right)^2
$$
is satisfied when $b<1.5$ and $f(r)$ has no singularity and approaches zero sufficiently fast when $r$ approaches infinity.

Is it physically invalid to test the behavior of particles around unstable potentials by putting singularities into the wave function? What does QFT have to say about this form of testing?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are trying to do. What do you mean by *"punching singularities into the wave function"*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Punching singularities means forcing the wavefunction to have singularities, but still maintain the normalizability condition.

Comment: @ACuriousMind If you flagged my question to be closed, you might as well tell me the reason why so I can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look normalizable. Normalizability is unrelated to which coordinate system you use (it's in e.g. $L^2(\mathbb R^{3n})$ or it isn't). The phrase "be belong" is not standard. And there is no choice of $a$ and $b$ that puts it in the form you mention, and it's a wave function anyway, not a potential. Is it supposed to be an energy eigenstate? Can you rewrite to be more clear?

Comment: @Timaeus I implemented your suggestions.

Comment: @linuxfreebird I still can't tell if you intend $\psi$ to be the wave function or instead be a solution to a radial equation from which you get the wavefunction. Similarly I can't tell if the potentials are effective potentials or actual physical potentials. I guess it didn't help that you didn't start with $\psi(r,\theta,\phi).$ I don't know what the mention about additional singularities at infinity is about, but it might be a grammar issue.

Comment: @Timaeus What happened to your solution?

Comment: @linuxfreebird It was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that goes wrong here is that the Hamiltonian is no longer a self-adjoint operator acting on these singular wave-functions.  Let's focus on the kinetic energy portion of the Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat K = - \partial_r^2 - {2 \over r} \partial_r = -{1 \over r^2} \partial_r r^2 \partial_r
$$
To prove self-adjointness, consider the natural inner product on two wave functions where we act with $\hat K$ on one of them
$$
\langle \phi, \hat K \psi \rangle = -\int_0^\infty \phi(r) \left({1 \over r^2} \partial_r r^2 \partial_r \psi(r) \right)r^2 dr
$$
We need to integrate by parts which introduces boundary terms at $r \to \infty$ and $r=0$.  The boundary term at $r \to \infty$ will vanish because the wave functions in question are exponentially damped.  Let's look at a boundary term at $r=0$:
$$
\langle \phi, \hat K \psi \rangle =  \int_0^\infty (\partial_r \phi)  (\partial_r \psi) r^2 dr + \lim_{r \to 0} r^2 \phi(r) \partial_r\psi(r)
$$
While the bulk integral over $r$ is nice and symmetric as it needs to be for self-adjointness, the boundary term is problematic for the wave functions in question.  If we let $\phi$ and $\psi$ scale as $1/r^b$ as $r \to 0$, the boundary term will scale as $r^{1 - 2b}$ as $r \to 0$, which is singular for $b>1/2$, or in particular for the values $b=3/4$ and $b=5/4$ used in the question.

One moral here is that self-adjointness (Hermiticity) is not just a local property of the operator.  It depends also sensitively on boundary conditions.  Here, we need non-singular boundary conditions at $r=0$ for the Hamiltonian to be a Hermitian operator.

Comment: Excellent answer. I did not consider the Hermiticity/B.C. of the problem.

Comment: Must we consider the possibility that the operator may still have real eigenvalues, but is not necessarily hermitian?

Comment: By assumption, observables in QM should be Hermitian operators.  If the operator is not Hermitian, it's no longer clear what you are computing.  I think you might be able to make your Hamiltonian Hermitian by adding some delta function like boundary term at $r=0$, but now physically it would become clearer what's going on -- you have bound states because of some additional local physics at $r=0$.

Comment: Wait local physics, is that when QFT comes into play?

Comment: This question was put on hold, does that mean everything will be deleted?

Comment: I had something like the Darwin term in mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure.  One can use Feynman diagram calculations in QFT to try to derive corrections to Schrodinger's equation for the hydrogen atom.  Some of these corrections may involve Dirac delta functions.    It's not clear to me that QFT is really needed here though -- were your wave functions physically motivated or just interesting mathematical examples?  Also, usually in this QFT context, the leading order Hamiltonian is already a Hermitian operator.

Comment: I was investigating the stability of solutions with very strong interactions.